# why is screen-reader browse mode not working?

Tags: accessibility

I am trying to make my client site accessible.

using NVDA/firefox I have problem navigating using the keyboard arrow/down in some parts of the content(browse mode).
I can't find the cause for this. the DOM order is good, there are no tabindex attribures ,so why can't I move fron one div to another using arrows?
so here is one example 
http://yad.your-site.co.il/park/visitors-center/
here is  screenshot -cant navigate with arrows
http://prnt.sc/ecbrnh

Comment: I don't have Hebrew installed with NVDA, just English, so it's hard for me to hear what's going on.  I hear 'link, link, link' as I tab around because NVDA can't read the text of the link.  Same if I use arrow up/down.  It can't read the text because I don't have the language, and even if I did, I wouldn't be able to tell if it was reading the right thing.  I looked at your screenshot but am not sure what your red arrows are pointing to.  The image, an H2, and something else?  I can use up/down arrows to navigate to most objects.  If a `<div>` doesn't have any text, you won't hear anything.

Comment: thank you very much after a few hours I found a role=application somewhere along the page  and that messed up the whole site

Comment: Role=application means you want all keyboard events sent directly to the application and to bypass the screen reader.  That would certainly explain the problem you're seeing.